# Is SQLFiddle broken? Errors for Oracle, SQL Server, ...?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sqlfiddle

I'm trying to create a simple table in [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) for Oracle database and keep getting the cryptic error:

> Create script error.

Here is a simple script it failed on:

```
create table t1 (f1 number, f2 number, f3 number);
```

Could anyone can help with that?

Comment: The View Sample Fiddle is giving an error as well. It works for the other database types.

Comment: The same error happens for MS SQL Server 2014 and 2008.

Comment: The error seems to be a little different today: the web service call is giving a 504 GATEWAY TIMEOUT error for MySQL, Oracle and MS SQL. Yesterday, the call return with 201 Completed, but it gives the error on interface.

Comment: SQLFiddle has been broken for Oracle for quite a while now.

Comment: Is there any other tool that could be used online as SQLFiddle?

Comment: @Walter_Ritzel Could you use https://apex.oracle.com/en/ as an alternative?

Comment: try https://livesql.oracle.com/

Comment: http://dbfiddle.uk is another alterntive.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

**UPDATE:** All seems to be working again. See [the answer from Jake Feasel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35735405/is-sqlfiddle-broken-errors-for-oracle-sql-server/37646270?noredirect=1#44610587) (the creator of SQL Fiddle).

<s>To summarise info from the comments as an answer and bring up to date as of writing:</s>

1. SQLFiddle was broken for about a year but as of 2017-07-07 it is working for [Oracle 11g R2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4).
2. It also seems to be broken for [MS SQL Server 2008](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d227f), [MS SQL Server 2014](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d227f) and [MySQL 5.5](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2) but [MySQL 5.6](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dafdd) is working.

*(Please comment if any of the above changes and I'll update the answer accordingly).*

**SQLFiddle Alternatives**

1. http://rextester.com has options for MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL and SQL Server in the "Language" dropdown (as well as the ability to save work online in a similar way to SQLFiddle).
2. http://db-fiddle.com has options for MySQL 5.5 / 5.6 / 5.7 / 8.0, PostgreSQL 9.4 / 9.5 / 9.6 / 10.0 and SQLite 3.16 / 3.17 / 3.18.
3. https://dbfiddle.uk has options for MariaDB 10.2 / 10.3, MySQL 8.0, Oracle 11g Release 2, Postgres 8.4 / 9.4 / 9.5 / 9.6 / 10 / 11, SQL Server 2012 / 2014 / 2016 / 2017 / 2017 (Linux) and SQLite 3.8 / 3.16 (as well as the ability to save work online in a similar way to SQLFiddle). See further discussion [here](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2686).
4. Suggested alternatives for Oracle are [Oracle Application Express](https://apex.oracle.com/en/) and [Oracle Live SQL](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/index.html).
5. A MySQL alternative with more limited functionality is [sqlize.com](http://sqlize.com/).
6. A clunky MySQL alternative is [sqltest.net](https://sqltest.net/) (if you can find your way around the adverts).
7. As a last resort, I've occasionally seen answers that use [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) to create custom queries (in SQL Server 2016) that aren't based on the built-in tables. [Disclaimer: I'm not sure it's really supposed to be used for this kind of purpose.]

Comment: In fact, what I would expect is some official communication from SQLFiddle team, as they have indicate SO as the mean to communicate with them, but you have summarized the findings so far quite well.

Comment: http://rextester.com is displaying no output for oracle. Just simply executing. Oracle Exp is not letting create stored procs and other limitations.

Comment: rextester.com was perfect for SQL Server.  Thanks much.

Comment: @SchmitzIT Please provide a link if possible or give further details about your schema as [the simple one linked above for MySQL 5.6](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dafdd) still seems to be working (at least some of the time).

Comment: @SteveChambers I think the issue was the script contained a function-name as the tablename. Fixed that, and it seems up and running again.

Comment: The reason it's working again is probably due to the fact that I've rewritten SQL Fiddle to use a new, much improved backend. See my answer to this question for more details :)

Comment: Nice work @JakeFeasel! Am particularly happy to see that some of the old saved fiddles in other answers that had temporarily broken are working again :-)

Answer (score 12):

if you are still interested in using SQL Fiddle I have some good news. Today I have gone live with a new version of the site which aims to improve both performance and reliability. If you are still having trouble, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Jake,  I am getting a bad gateway error when using SQL Fiddle - please help !  I am trying to run the following SQL code

Comment: CREATE TABLE Student(
      [ID]   int NULL ,
      [Name] [varchar](10) NULL)


INSERT into Student values(1, 'Bob')
INSERT into Student values(2, 'Alex')
INSERT into Student values(3, 'Mike')
INSERT into Student values(4, 'Melinda')
INSERT into Student values(5, 'Jane')
INSERT into Student values(6, 'Mary')

Comment: sqlfiddle.com isn't reachable as I tried now. Returns error:  Server Hangup