# Oracle SQLFiddle - Building schema Error

Tags: oracle11g, sqlfiddle

First time using SQLFiddle. I want to test Oracle sql. So on left panel, I paste this code which I got [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19141017/sql-fiddle-output-error)

```
create table Employee(
  name varchar2(100),
  id integer, 
  salary integer,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

This successfully executed. But when I change 1 of the column, I got script error:

```
create table Employee(
  sssssss varchar2(100),
  id integer, 
  salary integer,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Why? Can't I create any column name?

Comment: sql fiddle hasn't been working well with Oracle scripts for a while now.  There is nothing wrong with your script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLFiddle not working (errors for Oracle, SQL Server, ...?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35735405/sqlfiddle-not-working-errors-for-oracle-sql-server)

Comment: I see. thank you for saving my time